# How to insert data from Column A if Column B is Null and from Column B if Column A is Null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am thinking I am getting close but not sure:

I have an example Table containing email address, Personal and Work.
I am trying to create a new table which holds a single address.

Then insert an email address, example: If a user has a work email but no personal email, the insert work email and if no work email, insert personal email.

The following code does not work but it's just to show some of the many variations I have used:

USE EXAMPLE_DB

GO

```
CREATE TABLE USER_EMAIL(
 USER_NBR CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,EMAIL VARCHAR(30)NULL
)

GO

INSERT INTO USER_EMAIL(
 USER_NBR
,EMAIL
)

SELECT USER_NBR
,CASE WHEN EMAIL_ADDR IS NULL AND EMAIL_TYPE = 'Personal' THEN EMAIL_TYPE = 'Work' END EMAIL
,CASE WHEN EMAIL_ADDR IS NULL AND EMAIL_TYPE = 'Work'     THEN EMAIL_TYPE =  'Personal' END EMAIL
FROM EMAIL_DATA
```

Here is the table for the EMAIL_DATA:

```
USER_NBR   EMAIL_TYPE       EMAIL_ADDR
1          Personal 
2          Personal     user2personal@demo.com
3          Personal         user3personal@demo.com
4          Personal 
5          Personal         user5personal@demo.com
1          Work         user1work@demo.com
2          Work         user2work@demo.com
3          Work 
4          Work         user4work@demo.com
5          Work
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you show some sample data from `EMAIL_DATA`, along with desired `USER_EMAIL` content?

Comment: Sure, let me edit the original post.

Comment: If the user has both a work email and a personal email, insert both? For example, user 2 has both.

Comment: No, that was an error in the posting: In this scenario, the each user has one or the other. So the query will insert the address that is available, either work or personal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using `row_number`:

```
insert  user_email
        (user_nbr, email)
select  user_nbr
,       mail.email_addr
from    (
        select  user_nbr
        ,       email_addr
        ,       row_number() over (partition by user_nbr
                  order by
                  case 
                  when email_type = 'personal' then 1
                  when email_type = 'work' then 2
                  end) as rn
        from    email_data
        ) usr
where   usr.rn = 1
```

Since there are just two email types, you could also use `left join` twice:

```
insert  user_email
        (user_nbr, email)
select  user_nbr
,       coalesce(pers.email_addr, work.email_addr)
from    (
        select  distinct user_nbr
        from    email_data
        ) usr
left join 
        email_data as pers 
on      pers.user_nbr = usr.user_nbr
        and work.email_type = 'personal'
left join 
        email_data as work
on      work.user_nbr = usr.user_nbr
        and work.email_type = 'work'
```

Another approach that looks up the preferred email address using `cross apply`:

```
insert  user_email
        (user_nbr, email)
select  user_nbr
,       mail.email_addr
from    (
        select  distinct user_nbr
        from    email_data
        ) usr
cross apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    email_data mail
        where   mail.user_nbr = usr.user_nbr
                and mail.email_addr is not null
        order by
                case 
                when email_type = 'personal' then 1
                when email_type = 'work' then 2
                end
        ) mail
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirement clarification, where each user has only one type or another in the source, it sounds like you could simply do this:

```
INSERT INTO USER_EMAIL(USER_NBR, EMAIL_ADDR)
SELECT USER_NBR, EMAIL_ADDR
FROM EMAIL_DATA
WHERE EMAIL_ADDR IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: In the example data, user 2 has both types of email address

Comment: Aha!  In that case, this is the simplest solution +1

Answer (score 0):

This does following: If `EMAIL_ADDR` is null it'll look into the same table and search an email of the other email-type for the same user. Is it was you want?

```
INSERT INTO USER_EMAIL(
 USER_NBR
,EMAIL 
)
SELECT e.USER_NBR
     , EMAIL = COALESCE(e.EMAIL_ADDR
                    , (CASE e.EMAIL_TYPE
                        WHEN 'Work' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 EMAIL_ADDR  
                                      FROM EMAIL_DATA e1
                                      WHERE e1.USER_NBR=e.USER_NBR
                                      AND EMAIL_TYPE='Personal')
                        WHEN 'Personal' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 EMAIL_ADDR 
                                      FROM EMAIL_DATA e1
                                      WHERE e1.USER_NBR=e.USER_NBR
                                      AND EMAIL_TYPE='Work')
                    END))
FROM EMAIL_DATA e
```

Result with your sample data:

```
USER_NBR    EMAIL
1           user1work@demo.com
2           user2personal@demo.com
3           user3personal@demo.com
4           user4work@demo.com
5           user5personal@demo.com
1           user1work@demo.com
2           user2work@demo.com
3           user3personal@demo.com
4           user4work@demo.com
5           user5personal@demo.com
```

Comment: Not sure if the table contains a row like `1, 'Work', null` or if unknown emails are omitted.  Also, this would insert two rows for a person with both a work and a personal email address

Comment: @Andomar: I've just tried to use OP's schema. `USER_EMAIL` has only one field for email, so i've assumed that he wants two records if the user has email for both types provided.

Comment: Hmmm, if there are two rows `'Work', null` and `'Personal', 'joe@hotmail.com'`, this query would insert the personal email twice.  Might be what the OP wants, but unlikely :)

Comment: @Andomar: OP has added sample data. Now i see the problem ;)

Comment: Hello everyone and thanks for the replies: For now, I want to assumed that the USERS does not have both. Meaning each USER has one or the other. Sorry for the confusion in the example.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy: I'm not sure if i understand the requirement correctly. If one user cannot have both, what's wrong with a simple `SELECT USER_NBR,EMAIL_ADDR FROM EMAIL_DATA  WHERE EMAIL_ADDR IS NOT NULL`?